# The easiest method to get the pid of last process?

Tags: linux, bash

For example, how to do this:

```
$ job1 &
$ p1=$LASTPID
$ job2 &
$ p2=$LASTPID
$ wait $p1 $p2
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
job1 &
p1=$!
job2 &
p2=$!
wait
```

Answer (score 1):

If `bash` is your shell and you might stumble upon the following error, if you try to put all the statements into one line:

```
$ job1 & p1=$!; job2 & p2=$!; wait
-bash: !: event not found
```

The `!` character invokes [bash's history substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/19254). To get around this you need to add a space between the `$!` and the `;`, like this:

```
$ job1 & p1=$! ; job2 & p2=$! ; wait
[1] 20198
[2] 20199
...
```